# A simple function to square a number in assembly

Tags: nasm

My second day into assembly programming, I am trying to create a function to square a number
square.asm:

```asm
    global square: ; do not need _start because gcc has one already
    section .text
square:
    mov rax, rsi; remember: first argument is always in rsi. (Order is: rsi, rdi, rdx, tcx, r8, r9)
    mul rsi ; rax = rax * rsi (remember: accumulator is the implicit argument)
    ret ; returns the value in accumulator
```

main.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

long int square(long int);

int main() {
    for (long int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%li", square(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```txt
7556421251850319424-3765949904798924751-3765949904798924751-3765949904798924751-3765949904798924751
```

expected:

```txt
1491625
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first parameter is in `rdi`, not `rsi`, if you're using the [System V ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI).

Use:

```
mov ras, rdi
mul rdi
ret
```

To make the output easier to read, you'll also want some whitespace or a newline in your print statement:

```
printf("%li\n", square(i));
```

And one nitpick - use either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` for your `main` function signature. Anything else is undefined.